# Bugs in the Badge Pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/263/informed?userid=28182

I'm seeing this bug on a few of the badge pages, in both Firefox and Internet Explorer.

You can see the bug by either clicking the badges listed in a user profile, or from clicking the badges under the badge page itself.

[image: random dot or period above the badge, and the hyperlink to the 'about' page isn't rendered]

Obviously the link itself isn't being rendered, but only on badges that actually link off the page. [Yearling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=28182), for example, doesn't have a link. The dot however, is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, see this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191342/several-badge-descriptions-contain-raw-html) for details.

Comment: what about the dot (period)?

Comment: missed that one, fixing now...